# Rails 3, I need to save the current object and create another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have

```
recommendations has_many approvals
```

Basically a recommendation gets created with an approval.  The person who can approve it, comes in and checks an approve box, and needs to enter an email address for the next person who needs to approve (email is an attribute of an approval).

The caveat is that if the current_user has a user_type = SMT, then no more approvals are required.  Thats the last approval.

I am using the recommendation/:id/approval/:id/edit action. I think I just need a Class method for the Approval.  Something like:

```
before_save :save_and_create

def save_and_create
Some code that saves the current approval, creates a new one and asks me for the next admins email address, and send that user an email requesting that they approve
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this one out.  I simply created a before_save callback and the following method:

```
def create_next_approval
      next_approval = self.recommendation.approvals.build(:email => self.next_approver_email, :user_id  => User.find_by_email(next_approver_email))
      next_approval.save  if next_approver_email.present? && recently_approved? 
    end
```

hope it helps anyone else in my shoes.

Answer (score 0):

```
# old post
class Recommendation << AR
  validate :approval_completed?

  def approval_completed?
    if self.approvals.last.user.type == "SMT"
      return true
    else 
      return false # or a number for needed approvals: self.approvals.count >= 5
    end
  end
end 

# new solution
class Approval << AR
  validate :approvals_completed?

  def approvals_completed?
    if self.recommendation.approvals.last.user.type == "SMT"
      return true
    else 
      return false # or a number for needed approvals: self.approvals.count >= 5
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh i see you wanted a class method for approval.. I will change that.

Comment: This looks like the 2nd part of what I am trying to do... The first piece is the save and ask the user for a new email...  I can handle sending the email just don't know how to save and create another one

Comment: You mean, the approval, when adding a new email adress the approval should send an emial to the next approver?